# How to re-initiate RecyclerView scrolling

Tags: android

I have a RecyclerView attached to a CursorAdapter and my own custom RecyclerView.OnScrollListener. As the user scrolls to the top and pulls down, all the items are removed, and replaced with newer ones fetched from the network.

The problem is when the number of new items retrieved is small enough to fit on the screen(When it doesn't overflow), my custom onScrollListener, which I use to load the next page of items when scrolling down, is never activated. More specifically it's onScroll method is never called, since well, there aren't enough videos in the list to require needing scrolling down.

To get around this I've tried,

1. Calling `smoothScrollBy(0,0)` on the RecyclerView to have my `onScroll` method called
2. Calling `requestLayout()` on the RecyclerView

Both calls I made in `onLoadFinished` of my Loader after swapping the cursor having the new data, with the old.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove your scrollListener and add a view with custom touch listener on top of your recyclerView and check if you need to pull more data from it.

```
  class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

       boolean isFirstRowCompletelyVisible;

       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           switch (event.getAction()) {

               case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN://user put his finger on the screen.
                   isFirstRowCompletelyVisible = ((LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0;
                   break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:// user move his finger on screen.
                   if (isFirstRowCompletelyVisible) {
                   //calculate movement and decide if you want to pull new data from your server.
                   }
                   break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                   isFirstRowCompletelyVisible = false;
                   break;
           }
           return false;
       }
   }
```